# CSS url not working with leading slash

Tags: html, css, image, reactjs

I am trying to use a `background-image` using a "root-relative" path like so : `background-image: url("/img/bg.jpg");`.

The property is correctly showing in Chrome but the image does not appear. If I change it to be `http://localhost:8080/img/bg.jpg` it appears.

If I visit `http://localhost:8080/img/bg.jpg` the image is visible.

If I add a `<img style={{width:"100px", height:"100px"}} src="/img/bg.jpg"/>` it also appears properly (I am using React).

I browsed SO for a moment and noticed several people having issues with `url` but none of them was similar.

In case there is any kind of link, I'm using Less with webpack-dev-server. The image is in a static directory.

Comment: Should work. I suspect something is not as it seems.

Comment: Yes. What I don't understand is that Chrome is showing the right `background-image` value but it doesn't load it.

Comment: Same issue with Firefox. And when I hover over the url it says "Unable to load the image"

Comment: Your ´<img style={{width:"100px", height:"100px"}} src="/img/bg.jpg"/>´ is wrong. The correct way is ´<img style="width:100px; height:100px" src="/img/bg.jpg"/>´ I assume you made a similar error with ´background-color´.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to fix this issue thanks to [issue #2248](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2248).

I simply disabled the source maps for `css-loader` and `less-loader` and that made the trick.